# Performance problem get external page with classic asp on Windows 2019 server IIS10

Tags: windows, asp-classic

I have a problem loading an external page with classic asp on a **Windows 2019** server. I use the code below to load an external page. And it takes at least **40 seconds** for the page to load. **On Windows 2008 or 2012 it is loaded within a few seconds**. On the Windows 2019 server, real-time protection and the virus scanner are already disabled.

```
 <%
    url = "http://12.34.56.78/"
    set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false
    xmlhttp.send

    response.write xmlhttp.responseText
 %>
```

For `CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` I also have tried `CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")` and `CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")` or `CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`.

But it all makes no difference at all.

**Self Start Mode** to Always Run on the application pool and **Preload Enabled** to True on the website level does not have any effect.
Regular asp pages have no problem loading quickly.

Does anybody have any idea what this could be?

Comment: How quick does this XML load when you navigate to it directly via the browser from the 2019 box?

Comment: When I load the XML from the browser directly onto the server, it is displayed almost immediately

Comment: Same when performing a `Response.Redirect "http://12.34.56.78/"` ?

Comment: When I use the Response.Redirect the page is also loaded immediately.

Comment: OK, something weird going on with the`CreateObject` then, but that's gonna be tough to profile. Any specific reason you need to use classic ASP and cannot use .NET?

Comment: No, not a specific reasons. Only I have no idea how .Net works. And I also not know if it works or not with .NET

Comment: Try `Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")`, when using Classic ASP it's important to use `Server.Createobject()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it also makes no difference.

Comment: I may be have found a cause of the problem. I Get the following error in the event viewer:The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {0358B920-0AC7-461F-98F4-58E32CD89148} and APPID {3EB3C877-1F16-487C-9050-104DBCD66683} to the user IIS APPPOOL\iisuser SID (S-1-5-82-2427100359-558499284-4067031054-3529305503-3012502743) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: The above error message was unfortunately not the problem. The error message is now gone but the problem still exists. Think this is just a 2019 server issue. Because the entire performance of the servers is worse than the other server versions